# AngularJS: ng-checked not really binded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If ng-checked is evaluated to true, my checkbox html side should also be checked.
It's like if it was only done when initializing and not used anymore after.

I end with a difference in the result of ng-checked and what we can see on the browser.

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp',[]);
    
app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.testCheckedState = true;

  $scope.isTestChecked = function(){
    return $scope.testCheckedState;
  };

  $scope.forceCheck = function(){
    $scope.testCheckedState = true;
  };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/angular.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="isTestChecked()" ng-click="forceCheck()" />
      <br />
      isTestChecked: {{isTestChecked()}}
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

I then don't understand what makes a difference in those states ?

Thank you,
RoD

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="testCheckedState" />
```

Regards

Comment: Well, in this case it could do it, but what i really do is a little bit more complicated. ( i do a confirmation window in order to be sure that the user wants to launch an action, if he clicks yes we continue, if he clicks no we don't do anything and so i'd like to keep the checkbox in the previous state(the state of the ng-checked evaluation), as we haven't changed the model )

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="isTestChecked()" ng-click="forceCheck()" />
```

`ngChecked` is a **2-way data binding** and your expression is a function.  `ngChecked` has to be using a $scope variable. Like this.

```
<div ng-init="is_checked = false">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="is_checked" />
   <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="is_checked"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Indeed, i used a function, as i haven't found a real easy link with my model to get a real two way databinding (i don't want a link with a single element of model but with a property contained in X element ).
So i used a function to get a one-way data-binding, with the result of the function. Am I doing bad stuff ?